# How to join two tables with different numbers of rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I've already search the net about this but it can't solve my problem.

I have two tables one with 10 rows and other with 9 rows

table 1

```
RNUM       JOB_ID
---------- ---------- 
1          AC_ACCOUNT 
2          AC_MGR 
3          AD_ASST 
4          AD_PRES 
5          AD_VP 
6          FI_ACCOUNT 
7          FI_MGR 
8          HR_REP 
9          IT_PROG 
10         MK_MAN
```

table 2

```
RNUM       JOB_ID 
---------- ---------- 
1          AC_ACCOUNT 
2          AC_MGR 
3          AD_ASST 
4          AD_PRES 
5          AD_VP 
6          FI_ACCOUNT 
7          FI_MGR 
8          HR_REP 
9          IT_PROG
```

I want to join these two tables but I want the output to be like this

```
RNUM       JOB_ID            RNUM       JOB_ID 
---------- ----------        ---------- ---------- 
1          AC_ACCOUNT        null       null 
2          AC_MGR            1          AC_ACCOUNT 
3          AD_ASST           2          AC_MGR 
4          AD_PRES           3          AD_ASST 
5          AD_VP             4          AD_PRES 
6          FI_ACCOUNT        5          AD_VP 
7          FI_MGR            6          FI_ACCOUNT 
8          HR_REP            7          FI_MGR 
9          IT_PROG           8          HR_REP 
10         MK_MAN            9          IT_PROG
```

my first code is

```
select a.*, b.* 
from samp a, samp2 b where a.rnum = b.rnum(+)
```

but the result of my code is

```
RNUM       JOB_ID                RNUM       JOB_ID
---------- ----------            ---------- ---------- 
1          AC_ACCOUNT            1          AC_ACCOUNT 
2          AC_MGR                2          AC_MGR 
3          AD_ASST               3          AD_ASST 
4          AD_PRES               4          AD_PRES 
5          AD_VP                 5          AD_VP 
6          FI_ACCOUNT            6          FI_ACCOUNT 
7          FI_MGR                7          FI_MGR 
8          HR_REP                8          HR_REP 
9          IT_PROG               9          IT_PROG 
10         MK_MAN                null       null
```

I want to connect table 2's number 1 entry(AC_ACCOUNT) to table 1's number 2 entry(AC_MGR) as what you can see in my desired output.

I used rownum as a technique just to have a connection between my two tables.

I think I misunderstood left outer join here, please kindly enlighten me how to achieve my desired output.

Comment: both tables has AC_ACCOUNT why not connect tables with same AC_ACCOUNT?

Comment: You have no ORDER BY so there will be no order.  Also your join is on a.rnum=b.rnum but that's not what your desired results are. Very confusing as to what you want! You can do where a.rnum is b.rnum+1 but I suspect it's not exactly that you want

Comment: @user7294900 Hi, thanks for the reply, but what do you mean by connect them with AC_ACCOUNT?  Both tables actually have the same data, excluding the last one in table 1.

Comment: Please explain the logic for when your two tables have more differences. What if table2 has a key that table1 does not have? What it table1 has three keys that table2 does not have? What if they have nothing in common? Do you have a generic logic?

Comment: @LoztInSpace Hi, thanks for the reply. That's actually my 2nd try and it didnt work out well too. 

select a.*, b.*
from samp a
left outer join samp2 b
on a.rnum = b.rnum+1 



That resulted to same output only that the table 1 starts now at 2(WC_MGR) and its 10th data is the no. 1(AC_ACCOUNT).  Did I wrote the code youre expecting or not?

Comment: @trincot Hi, thanks for the reply. I just took this table from oracle sql dev for me to practice on. I just want an output that, table 2's first row will be matched on to table 1's 2nd row. And the first row of 2nd table would be null because table 2 is one row lesser than the other. I just add rownum for me to at least have something for them to connect each other. Do you get me? Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: @LoztInSpace Also what do you mean by that Order By? Where do I have to order by this?

Comment: @LoztInSpace Hi, i get now your answer and it worked with that order by. Thanks. I dont know how to mark your answer as the correct one here, only upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this query will do the job:

```
Select a.*, b.* 
From samp a 
Left Outer Join samp2 b On b.rnum + 1 = a.rnum
Order by a.rnum;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. How would it look like in that with (+) format? I tried this but error, select a.*, b.* from samp a, samp2 b where (+) b.rnum+1 = a.rnum order by a.rnum

Comment: I discourage use of that Oracle-specific outer join syntax because it's not portable, but it would look like `select a.*, b.* from samp a, samp2 b where b.rnum(+) +1 = a.rnum order by a.rnum`.